# android xml put component on top with layout_gravity="center"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, admob, layout-gravity

I'm trying to put `admob` ad at the top of my `app` but the normal text needs to stay centered in the middle... with the below code only one of the components are displayed..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/test.testpkg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding = "10dip" >

    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
        myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" />

    <test.testpkg.CustomTextView android:id="@+id/landscapeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor = "#000"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:shadowColor="#FFF"
        android:shadowDx="1.2"
        android:shadowDy="1.2"
        android:shadowRadius="1.2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text ="Test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout has an additional attribute android:orientation [(doc).](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation)
The default value ist "horizontal", but you need "vertical", because at the moment the CustomTextView gets rendered right of the AdView and outside of the screen.

Additional hint: if you want your CustomTextView really in den middle of the screen, you should use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and add the attribut android:layout_centerInParent="true" -> gets displayed in the middle.